# Why will use the script the Bourne Shell instead of the written bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, bourne-shell

I write a script who should login to a server via ssh and do something there. So I write two parts. First part:

```
myLoginPassword="loginpassword"
sshpass -p $myLoginPassword ssh -t user@machine
```

Works fine.
Second part:

```
mySudoPassword="sudopassword"
/bin/bash -c "su -c - myadminuser <<< $mySudoPassword whoami"
```

If I run the first part and then run the second part on the target machine, it works fine.

Now, I want to join this two parts into one:

```
sshpass -p $myLoginPassword ssh -t user@machine /bin/bash -c "su -c - myadminuser <<< $mySudoPassword whoami"
```

But now, I get the error message:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

The origin of the error is, that the Bourne Shell can not handle the here-string. But why is it now a Bourne Shell and not the bash, if I write `/bin/bash -c` to use the bash?